# Python Tkinter Format Number Entry with commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like to know how to convert a number into a formatted "number" format that has commas. I am on Mac OSX. An expression is inputted and evaluated within an entry widget and then output into a label widget with the following function:

```
def evaluate(self, event):
    data = self.e.get()
    self.ans.configure(text = "Answer: " + str(eval(data)))
```

I need the resulting output to be in a "number" format. For example, if the output is "34523000", I want it to say "34,523,000".

Comment: do you need a number, to perform a calculation, or a formated string of this number ?

Comment: @PRMoureu The code that I need is the final step AFTER the evaluation is already done. So, I need a formatted version of the output of the evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/locale.html) module.

If you are on Ubuntu, you can check the list of your locales by typing `locale -a` on your Terminal. On my machine, I see a long list from which I choose, for example, '`en_US.utf8`'.

Once you have done that, go back to your function and do these changes:

```
import locale
# ...
# ...
# It is better to run this outside your function:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
# ...
# ...
def evaluate(self, event):
    entry_data = self.e.get()
    data = locale.format("%d", entry_data, grouping=True)
    # ...
    # ...
```

Here is a quick demo with the example data you provided:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
'en_US.utf8'
>>> locale.format("%d", 34523000, grouping=True)
'34,523,000'
```

Comment: I am using Mac OSX with Spyder - would this still work with Mac?

Comment: The command I provided [should work](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/locale.1.html) on OS X . The program also @oezeadi

Comment: I tried doing it but getting the error: "unsupported locale setting". I put the locale.setlocale line into the init function of my class. Should I put that in the function?

Comment: You must first type the command `locale -a`  to see the list of locales you have set in your machine, then pick one of them and write it in place of `en_US.utf8` @oezeadi

Comment: I found it - it is en_US.UTF-8. I put that in, no error occurred, but the function didn't work.

Comment: Fixed it! I was making a small error. It works - thank you!

Comment: One question: what does "%d" mean? And what else does the locale function do? Is there a list of other types of number formats it can do?

Comment: `%d` is used as a placeholder for numbers (it is useful to format strings)